# Why is the cohen's d effect-size from this study so different from the value I've computed manually?

Tags: mixed-model, confidence-interval, effect-size, pooling, cohens-d

In this study [1], they estimate an overall cohen's d effect-size of .70; however, when I try to compute the cohen's d using their means/stds, I get a much smaller effect-size of .47.

Am I doing something wrong in my cohen's d calculation?

Here is the data from table 2A in the paper [1], and the effect-size calculation that I'm doing:

- Active group improvement: 7.3
- Placebo group improvement: 1.7
- Net improvement: 5.6
- Pooled std: 11.9 (see below for computation)
- cohen's d: 5.6 / 11.9 = .47 (whereas they give "cohen's d" as .70 in the same table)

Also, I'm getting the pooled std as follows (from the same table), using the assumption that the 95% interval is approximately +/- 2 SE:

- 95% confidence-interval baseline (active): +/- 4.1 (+/- 2*std/sqrt(n))
- 95% confidence-interval baseline (placebo): +/- 5.4 (+/- 2*std/sqrt(n))
- std baseline (active): sqrt(23)*4.1/2 = 9.8 (n=23)
- std baseline (placebo): sqrt(25)*5.4/2 = 13.5 (n=25)
- pooled std = 11.9

  - i.e.: sqrt( (22 * 9.8^2 + 24 * 13.5^2)/46) = 11.9

Also, I notice that if you don't exclude the placebo improvement, then the effect size is: 7.3 / 11.9 = .61 (which is closer to their .70 value, though not quite the same); however, I assume that you should exclude placebo improvement from an effect size estimate?

[Edit: made significant edits based on comment from @B.Liu]

[1] https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5794882/

Comment: When you "convert" the CI of the mean improvement (which, if normal assumptions apply, has half-width of 2 standard _errors_) to standard deviation, have you multiply the $\sqrt{n}$ back on?

Comment: Thanks. You're right that I was incorrectly using std rather than SE.  When I include the sqrt correction the pooled std becomes 11.9, which gives a cohen's d of 5.6/11.9 = .47, which is now much lower than their estimate. It occurs to me that they might not be subtracting out the placebo effect-size, which would give .61 (which is closer, but I assume the effect size should exclude placebo portion).  Note I'm not using the std/CI of the "improvement", but of the baseline distribution (curious for your thoughts, but 'll edit/update the question).

Comment: It's unclear where you're getting all these stats from.  In Table 2A, where these Cohen's d values appear, they are perfectly consistent with the associated confidence intervals.  The CI of $(1.0,10.4)$ for the "overall" effect corresponds to a standard error of $(10.4-1.0)/1.645/2 = 2.85,$ for instance, rather than your "pooled SD" of $11.9.$  I cannot find any "pooled SD" values in that table.

Comment: I assumed that test subjects between the active and placebo groups are probably paired between baseline and 12 weeks. The difference between 12 weeks and baseline is likely to have a very different CI/standard deviation figures as compared to the CI/standard deviation for the baseline figures. I don't think the Cohen's d is verifiable (even roughly) given only what's in Table 2A of the paper.

Comment: @whuber: I updated with details of the pooled stdev calculation, but not sure which part you are objecting to.  Note my understanding is that the pooled stdev of the baseline distribution is used to normalize cohen's d, not the stdev of the distribution of deltas/improvements.

Comment: @B.Liu I can't find any evidence that the placebo and active subjects were paired in this study.  Also, per my prev comment, my understanding is that the distribution of scores (e.g. at baseline) is used to normalize the cohen's d, not the distribution of improvements.  For instance, if a treatment affects everyone about the same, there will be low variance in the improvement-deltas, but that doesn't mean the effect size is large (the deltas might be large or small compared to sample or population variance in that case)?

Comment: Clarification: Verifying Cohen's d using the OP's approach ground up from each individual group is near-impossible. Roughly verifying the same quantity using the mean and CI of improvement (as suggested by @whuber) is doable. The multi-level design does create some odd $\sqrt{2}$ in the calculations that needs to be handled carefully.

Comment: @Andy Re: pairing. Apologies, bad wording on my part. I meant within the placebo and active groups respectively, the subjects are assumed to be paired when their baseline and 12 week measurements are taken. Hence the variance of (active_12-weeks - active_baseline) can be drastically different from the variance of active_12-weeks or the variance of active_baseline, or the latter two's sum. In fact, I'd expect them to be quite a bit smaller as the responses from each test unit are probably correlated.

Comment: @B.Liu  I'm not sure if I understand, but why is the variance of the improvements relevant?  I haven't found any source that recommends normalizing effect sizes based on the variance of the deltas.  In particular, you could have a small improvement relative to population variance in the underlying metric (low cohen's d), but the treatment might affect everyone about the same.  In that case, we wouldn't normalize by the small variance in improvements, and conclude the effect size was large?  Btw, if you are able to provide an answer below with more details that would certainly be appreciated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122512/discussion-between-b-liu-and-andy).